# How can I loop through a nested std::map starting from the exterior?

Tags: c++

My Google skills fail me =(

I have the following map:

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>> spriteSheetMap;
```

And I'm trying to do this:

```
for (auto &animationKey : killerRabbit->spriteSheetMap) {
    for (auto &animation : animationKey) {
        //why doesn't this work?
    }            
}
```

The actual error:

```
Invalid range expression of type 'std::__1::pair<const std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char> > > > >'; no viable 'begin' function available
```

Comment: You should specify How it doesn't work in your question -- what error do you get or what is unexpected by your output.

Comment: @Pyrce
Oops, added the error, the confusing thing is that the first loop works, and the second loop is of the same type, I can't quite warp my head around this =s

Comment: The killerRabbit is all over SO today :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first loop invokes [`begin()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/begin/) which returns `std::pair`'s (i.e. `value_type` of `std::map`'s). So it doesn't make much sense to iterate over a pair like that. I think what you want is:

```
for (auto &animation : animationKey.second) {
```

Which will iterate over the inner-map. Just remember that the same thing will happen with `animation`: `animation` will be a pair, with `animation.first` referring to the key and `animation.second` referring to the value.

Comment: @Pyrce Haha sorry, I know that feeling ;(

Comment: I'd give both a tick if it were possible, you were both very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

The error is saying it can't iterate over a pair. The following fixes the problem as you're getting the key-value pair result from iterating over a map in the first loop.

```
for (auto &animation : animationKey.second)
```

See [map.begin()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/begin/) to see examples of how the first loop outputs pairs and not values to the auto variable.